# Facing error in setting TCP/IP port number

Tags: visual-studio, intel-oneapi

On integrating the oneapi toolkit and VS, I am getting error on selecting the TCP/IP port in the options section.
I can't set it as 0 or anything as it is showing 'Invalid Debugger Port Number'
and I do not have a GDB distribution. I can't move forward without setting this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the TCS/IP Port value to 1234
as it is the default for Intel oneAPI using Microsoft Visual Studio.